# How would I create a Polaroid Effect for Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, photo, photos

I am trying to figure out how to create a Polaroid effect for Photos in an app I am creating.. I have looked everywhere and cant figure out where to start..

I need something like this :

[image]

Comment: Could you describe the effect a bit more, or perhaps link some mock screenshots of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The white border / drop shadow effect http://i.imgur.com/fQ3zL.png

Comment: Finally, a good use of the accelerometer. Shake it, shake it, shake it like a Polaroid picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) drawable as the background of your container view. The padding supplied by the 9-patch will help position your content within the frame.